# comparing strings and calculating occurrence

Tags: python, string, list, math

I don't know how to attack this problem.

I have 3 lists with a word, a tag and a number it appears on a document:

```
v1 = [['be', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['scott', 'NP00000', 2], ['north', 'NCMS000', 1], ['revolution', 'NP00000', 1], ['name', 'VMP00SM', 1]]
v2 = [['mechanic', 'NCMS000', 1], ['be', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['tool', 'AQ0CS0', 1], ['sam', 'NP00000', 1], ['frida', 'NP00000', 1]]
v3 = [['be', 'VSIP3S0', 1], ['scott', 'NP00000', 1], ['who', 'NP00000', 1]]
```

How can I build a function that receiving these lists compare each word so that, for example, the word `be` in `v1` appears in the three lists once, in that case append onto a result list `(1 * log(3/3))`, where 1 -> maximum value of occurrence (which is the 3rd element of the sublist), log numerator 3 -> constant, log denominator 3 -> because the word appears on `v1`, `v2` and `v3`.

Next we have `scott` -> In this case append onto the result list `(2 * log(3/2))`, 2 -> maximum word´s value of occurrence, log numerator 3 -> constant, log denominator 2 -> because the word 'scott' appears on `v1` and `v2`.

Next we have `north` -> In this case append onto the result list `(1 * log(3/1))`, 1 -> maximum word´s value of occurrence, log numerator 3 -> constant, log denominator 1 -> because the word 'north' appears only `v1`.

Next we have `revolution` -> In this case append onto the result list `(1 * log(3/1))`, 1 -> maximum word´s value of occurrence, log numerator 3 -> constant, log denominator 1 -> because the word 'north' appears only `v1`.

Next we have `name` -> In this case append onto the result list `(1 * log(3/1))`, 1 -> maximum word´s value of occurrence, log numerator 3 -> constant, log denominator 1 -> because the word 'name' appears only `v1`.

Furthermore we have to do the same with `v2` by comparing `mechanic`, `be`, `tool`, etc. with the other words, calculate the max value of occurrence and multuplying it `w/ log(3/?)` depending if the word appears or not in `v1` and `v3`.

This is my attempt for `v1`:

```
def f1(v1, v2, v3):
    res =[]
    for e in v1:
        if e != 0:
            if e in v2 and e in v3:
                res.append(0)
            elif e in v2:
                res.append(e * math.log(3/2))
            else:
                res.append(e * math.log(3))
    return res
```

returning: `[0, 2.1972245773362196, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

and this is obviously not the result

it should return something like:

```
[['be', 0.47], ['scott', 0.35 ], ['north', 0.47], ['revolution', 0.47], ['north', 0.47]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your description, I got

```
import math
v1 = [['be', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['scott', 'NP00000', 2], ['north', 'NCMS000', 1], ['revolution', 'NP00000', 1], ['name', 'VMP00SM', 1]]
v2 = [['mechanic', 'NCMS000', 1], ['be', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['tool', 'AQ0CS0', 1], ['sam', 'NP00000', 1], ['frida', 'NP00000', 1]]
v3 = [['be', 'VSIP3S0', 1], ['scott', 'NP00000', 1], ['who', 'NP00000', 1]]

v = [v1,v2,v3]

countdict = {}
for vi in v:
    for e in vi:
        countdict[e[0]] = countdict.get(e[0],0) + 1

scoredict = {}
for vi in v:
    for e in vi:
        scoredict[e[0]] = scoredict.get(e[0],0) + (e[2] * math.log10(3.0/countdict[e[0]]))

print scoredict
```

I save the output as a dict, which is:

```
{'be': 0.0, 'revolution': 0.47712125471966244, 'north': 0.47712125471966244, 'name': 0.47712125471966244, 'sam': 0.47712125471966244, 'tool': 0.47712125471966244, 'who': 0.47712125471966244, 'scott': 0.5282737771670437, 'mechanic': 0.47712125471966244, 'frida': 0.47712125471966244}
```

Comment: Thanks David it is pretty much the result!!! One remark: python math log(3) throws 1.098 but a normal calculator shows 0.47... why?

Comment: What is the log base you need?

Comment: I need to chg math.log(x) for math.log10(x)

Comment: @David.Zheng I implemented your solution and is giving me: countdict[e[0]] = countdict.get(e[0],0) + 1
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @JPP, it's strange to catch such an exception which means type of countdict is int in your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36450/discussion-between-jpp-and-david-zheng)